# Finding Same Duplicate Data coming from 2 files

Tags: sql

I have a Table where 8 columns is there. Where data is been populating by Informatica from Files. Now there is a column where we are populating processed filename. Now client requirement is to check whether Same data is coming from 2 Files? I have checked and found duplicates in Table. But how to find this kind of record have no clue.

Comment: if you cannot connect the data in tables with the files processed, then there is no way to find your duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col1, col2 ...
       count(file_name_column)
from the_table
group by col1, col2 ...
having count(file_name_column) > 1
```

You group by columns where duplicates are possible and count **different** values of the source file name column. 
Then leave only cases where different sources count is more than 1 (2 differnet file sources) by the `having` check.

Comment: Let me try this 